# Invalid object name 'dbo.trgAfterUpdate' - Trigger Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I created a trigger for my application that will allow me to keep a history of records that are edited in my grid.

I get the error: Invalid object name 'dbo.trgAfterUpdate'. and not sure why.

Here is my trigger:

```
USE [TestTable]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trgAfterUpdate]    Script Date: 2/25/2014 6:31:25 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterUpdate] ON [dbo].[summary] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    declare @ID int;
    declare @CR varchar(50);
    declare @Product varchar(50);
    declare @Description varchar(MAX);

    select @ID=i.ID from inserted i;    
    select @CR= i.CR from inserted i;   
    select @Product = i.Product from inserted i;    
    select @Description=i.Description from inserted i;  

    if update(Product)
        Set @Summary = 'Old value was: ' + (Select Product from deleted) + ' New Value is: ' + (Select Product from inserted)
        set @Changes_Made='Updated Record -- After Update Trigger.';

        insert into History(ID,Product,Description,Changes_Made,Audit_Timestamp, Summary) 
    values(@ID,@Product,@Description,@Changes_Made,getdate(), @Summary);
```

Any help on how to fix this would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just confirm the table exists first.  Try this:

```
use [TestTable]
GO

select * from [dbo].[summary]
```

If you get a message that the table doesn't exist, then you know what the problem is :)

Comment: Is this a NEW trigger or an existing one?  I just noticed that your SQL statment is using an ALTER statement.  It should be using CREATE TRIGGER instead.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that I didn't refresh local cache.
So I

> Ctrl + Shift + R

and voilà.

Answer (score 1):

This typically means 1 of 2 things.

- you've referenced an object (table, trigger, stored procedure,etc)
  that doesn't actually exist (i.e., you executed a query to update a
  table, and that table doesn't exist).
- The table exists, but you didn't reference it correctly

Try with database name

Like

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbName].[dbo].[trgAfterUpdate] ON [dbName].[dbo].[summary] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
```

Comment: can you Recreate a trigger

Comment: I tried going through the process but the code I am using I got help with...not really sure how to start from scratch. Can you provide a little guidance on that?

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means the trigger  'dbo.trgAfterUpdate' doesn't exist.
Use 'CREATE ' instead of 'ALTER ' to create the trigger.
ALTER is used to modify existing trigger.